# Open image from assetfolder when listview is clicked

Tags: android, listview, imageview

I want to open image from assets folder in imageview.I have the names of the images in list view .Whenever user press any list item it should display another layout file in which there will be image shown in imageview.different list item with different images.So if possible please provide some pseudo code..i have this list view.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    CopyReadAssets();
            AssetManager asset = getAssets();
    try {
        final String[] arrdata = asset.list("IMAGEfolder");
        List<String> imagelist = new ArrayList<String>();
        int size = arrdata.length;
        for(int i = 0;i<size;i++)
        {
          if(arrdata[i].contains(".png"))

          {
            imagelist.add(arrdata[i]); 
           }
        }
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter= new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,imagelist);
        ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
             public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                        int position, long id) {
                if(position == 0 ) {
Intent intent = new Intent(Advertise.this,Advertise_image.class);
                intent.putExtra("name", imagelist.get(position).toString());
                startActivity(intent);
}
```

Here is my Adertise_image.java file

```
public class Advertise_image extends Activity {
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.advertise_image);
    InputStream ip =null;
    try {
        ip=getAssets().open("ImageFolder/"+getIntent().getStringExtra("name"));
        Bitmap bitmap=BitmapFactory.decodeStream(ip);
        ImageView iv = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.advertiseimage);
        iv.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
    }catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }finally {
        if(ip!=null)
            try {
                ip.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
    }
}
```

}

Here is my layout file

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/advertiseimage"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
      />
</RelativeLayout>
```

My stacktrace is as follows

```
    04-16 16:29:52.112: W/System.err(1106): java.io.FileNotFoundException: icon.png
04-16 16:29:52.122: W/System.err(1106):     at android.content.res.AssetManager.openAsset(Native Method)
04-16 16:29:52.122: W/System.err(1106):     at android.content.res.AssetManager.open(AssetManager.java:315)
04-16 16:29:52.122: W/System.err(1106):     at android.content.res.AssetManager.open(AssetManager.java:289)
04-16 16:29:52.122: W/System.err(1106):     at com.example.allahummalabbaik.Advertise_image.onCreate(Advertise_image.java:20)
04-16 16:29:52.132: W/System.err(1106):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4465)
04-16 16:29:52.132: W/System.err(1106):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1049)
04-16 16:29:52.132: W/System.err(1106):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1920)
04-16 16:29:52.132: W/System.err(1106):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1981)
04-16 16:29:52.132: W/System.err(1106):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:123)
04-16 16:29:52.132: W/System.err(1106):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1147)
04-16 16:29:52.142: W/System.err(1106):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
04-16 16:29:52.142: W/System.err(1106):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
04-16 16:29:52.152: W/System.err(1106):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
04-16 16:29:52.152: W/System.err(1106):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-16 16:29:52.152: W/System.err(1106):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
04-16 16:29:52.152: W/System.err(1106):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
```

Finally Solved My problem ..Thank you all Guys For great help....

Comment: next layout, you mean new screen?

Comment: open a new activity on item click..pass the filename using intent and set the image in imageview accordingly..

Comment: where have u written **icon.png**??

Comment: Its my file name that is in ImageFolder in assets

Comment: There is no such file as expection says...

Comment: when i put outside my Folder then problem is solved but if i put file inside my Imagefolder inside assets then file not found exception arises....

Comment: then check the path..you must be passing wrong path..

Comment: How shud i pass path in this line getAssets().open(getIntent().getStringExtra("name"));

Comment: **getIntent().getStringExtra("name")** is what are you getting after passing it from item click as : **imagelist.get(position).toString()**... SO check imagelist.get(position).toString()

Comment: You can see **final String[] arrdata = asset.list("IMAGEfolder");** the image is coming in list view from image folder

Comment: Anybody help me out...

Answer (score 1):

I don't exactly get what you mean by next layout file but I assume it is another activity. So here you go:

In your onitemclick, pass the string to the other activity:

```
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                        int position, long id) {

        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this , YourImageViewActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("image" , imagelist.get(position).toString());
        startActivity(intent);
}
```

On your imageview activity, call this to set the image to an imageview:

```
            InputStream yourBitmap=null;

            try {
                yourBitmap = getAssets().open(getIntent().getStringExtra("image"));
                Bitmap bitmap=BitmapFactory.decodeStream(yourBitmap);
                imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                if(yourBitmap!=null)
                    yourBitmap.close();
            }
```

If you meant in the same layout, just set the string on click to a global string, and use the second code I provided for setting it to your imageview.

Comment: I am still not able to open image in my image view it is giving me blank page. no image is diplayed in imageview using above code...

Comment: if try is failing, can you give your stacktrace so we can see your error? because this is working for me without problems.

Comment: java.io.FileNotFoundException: icon.png
according to this, there is no "icon.png" file in your assets. can you try changing this and test your code with an existing image from your assets folder: 

yourBitmap = getAssets().open("any_image_in_asset.png");

Comment: Ya i found out my problem my file was in folder that i created inside assets folder...now if i want to open file from folder how to open it...

Answer (score 0):

try below code:-

```
private Bitmap getBitmapFromAsset(String strName)
    {
        AssetManager assetManager = getAssets();
        InputStream istr = null;
        try {
            istr = assetManager.open(strName);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(istr);
        return bitmap;
    }
```

http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2012/02/android-read-file-from-assets.html

Comment: I guess this is not what he wants

Comment: ya i  have images in my assets folder and i have to open that images on click event of listview item.Different listview item with different images have to be opened in imageview

Comment: Check itsrajesh4uguys's answer and ma comment too @user3387601

Comment: @user3387601 you can see my answer for passing and setting it in another activity.

Comment: @SweetWisherツ itsrajesh4uguys gave the same code piece I provided 10 mins later..

Comment: @SirSC exactly...actually i saw your answer only but copied wrong name :P

Comment: @SweetWisherツ  i am still not able to solve it .I have your code but not able to solve it i have also edited my answer plz have a look at it

Answer (score 0):

Hope this code will help you

```
InputStream bitmap=null;

    try {
        bitmap=getAssets().open("icon.png");
        Bitmap bit=BitmapFactory.decodeStream(bitmap);
        img.setImageBitmap(bit);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if(bitmap!=null)
        bitmap.close();
    }
```

Comment: Hmm sorry if I offend, but I already wrote the exact code in my answer 10 mins ago. Didn't get your purpose.